Geometry Nodes: How to get new geometry to face away from the geometry it is spawning on?
I'm super new to geometry nodes and Blender in general. I'm making the forest scene using geometry nodes and was hoping there's a way to calculate the leaves rotation such that they always face away from the branch they are being placed on.
My scene currently and the nodes




P.S. Currently by plugging the Distribute points rotation into the rotation input on Instance on Points I can get the leaves to follow the faces in their rotation I'm hoping to make them more perpendicular to the face they're on.

Please don't use links to images in your question. The images can be inserted directly into your question where they will remain available to people researching your question in future. How to upload an image to a post. Thanks.
